# How do I update a widget based on changes in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ipywidgets

I am working towards creating a custom widget to display spreadsheets in a Jupyter notebook using the [cookiecutter template](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/widget-cookiecutter). The first thing that I started with was displaying a dataframe in the table. This works well, however, the table does not update when changes are made to the dataframe.

Does anyone have any hints on how to auto update a widget based on changes to a dataframe? Is there a way to monitor changes made to a pandas dataframe so that the widget can know about these changes?

Thanks in advance for your help!